# System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied. (MySQL)

Tags: database, windows-services, mysql-workbench, mysql

I tried to start the newly installed MySQL server (V 5.5.15 on Windows Vista) using the `mysqld` command in the command prompt, but resulted the following error:

When I use `mysqld` command:

```
C:\Users\Panora>mysqld
110914 16:23:02 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Panora-PC.lower-test
110914 16:23:02 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\Panora-PC.lower-test
mysqld: File '.\mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
110914 16:23:02 [ERROR] Aborting

110914 16:23:02 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete


C:\Users\Panora>
```

When I use `NET START` command:

```
C:\Users\Panora>NET START MySQL55
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.


C:\Users\Panora>
```

Additional notes:

(1) I'm able to start and stop the server using the MySQLWorkbench visual UI without any problems

(2) I'm able to stop the server using the command line without any problem using this command `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because of wrong permissions (denied). Check the user under which mysql is supposed to start and the permissions of the data directory.

Comment: The user is "root" who is assigned all privileges. I tried with the command "mysqld -u root" as well (which results the same error message)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-create.html Also read the comments.

Comment: "It's Vista's "User Account Control" prohibiting admin rights. If this is turned off, everything works as expected." Refer: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,189284,189287#msg-189287

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer. This problem is because Windows Vista is restricting write to Program Files. And if you write it will only write to temporary files. You could try to turn off UAC but I would recommend to move the data folder to an other location. Not under program files.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Command Prompt** as **administrator**:

[image]

Then, you can start **MySQL** as shown below:

```
C:\Windows\System32>net start MySQL80
The MYSQL80 service is starting.
The MYSQL80 service was started successfully.
```

In addition, you can stop **MySQL** as well:

```
C:\Windows\System32>net stop MySQL80
The MYSQL80 service is stopping.
The MYSQL80 service was stopped successfully.
```